# magento 2 customer sidebar at admin tab remove the newsletter

Tags: tabs, magento2, admin, sidebar

how can I remove the 2 side tabs in customer tab at admin side please have a look in attachment 
https://prnt.sc/s76tjx

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_edit_tab_view">
    <referenceBlock name="customer.billing.agreement.grid" remove="true" /> <!-- Not working -->
    <referenceBlock name="billing" remove="true" /> <!-- Not working -->
    <referenceBlock name="billing-agreement" remove="true" /> <!-- Not working -->
</referenceBlock>
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, the easiest way to "remove" the newsletter (or whatever other section you want) without touching Magento's core files is to edit the user(s) roles. Thus, you can customize users permissions by role and create different roles for different users:

1. Go to <kbd>System</kbd> > <kbd>User Roles</kbd> and click on the respective role (e.g. <kbd>Administrators</kbd>)
2. Go to <kbd>Role Resources</kbd> and uncheck the <kbd>Newsletter Section</kbd> option under <kbd>Stores</kbd>. (If no resources are shown but a selector with <kbd>All</kbd> is selected, change it to <kbd>Custom</kbd> and then choose all resources but the ones you don't want)

After saving changes, unchecked resources are no longer available for users with this role.

[image: A print with all roles selected but <code>Newsletter Section</code>]